# Error when starting the Spark shell on Ubuntu : Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: apache-spark

I installed Spark 2.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Java 1.8, following these steps:

https://github.com/ashishtam/apache-spark-multi-node-installation/blob/master/index.md

I have a simple cluster made of 1 master and 1 slave, the /etc/hosts file being

```
# For Spark cluster
172.16.10.20 master
172.16.10.30 slave01

#127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Once Spark installed and configured, I started the master and the slaves

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
./sbin/start-slaves.sh spark://master-pc:7077
```

checking the status with jps, on the master node:

```
   > jps
    13440 Master
    13701 Worker
    13963 Jps
```

and on the slave node:

```
> jps
4202 Master
4332 Worker
4958 Jps
```

On the master node, when opening the spark-shell I got:

```
18/08/30 19:12:38 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://master:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = spark://master:7077, app id = app-20180830191300-0000).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
    at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:169)
    at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:137)
    at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:246)
    at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:261)
    at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:198)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2145)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2349)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2269)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readOneLine(JLineReader.scala:57)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$class.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readLine(JLineReader.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.readOneLine(ILoop.scala:404)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:413)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

and it broke...
by curiosity I did the same on the slave node:

```
18/08/30 19:18:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/08/30 19:18:43 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:364)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
  at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:364)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I ended up with a spark shell, but errors about a spark-driver.

I have checked the IP in /etc/hosts, the SPARK_HOME variable in the master node, the configuration files of Spark, the ssh keys... 
the spark local ip is also defined as (for the master node):

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=172.16.10.20
```

does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: For the master node this crash has been sorted out by rebooting the machine. But the spark-shell keeps on complaining when starting on the slave node, which may arise from that fact that Spark expects the shell to be used in Master only. (BTW I also tried to add SPARK_HOME to the bashrc of the slave, and checked JAVA_HOME, no effect)